# Point of intersect for two lines tangent to two quadratic equations.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was given the question:

> Sketch the graphs of $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2+6x-5$, and sketch the two lines that are tangent to both graphs. Find equations of these lines.

in my calculus(I) homework. I [solved](http://calcchat.com/book/Calculus-10e/2/2/77/) this problem. The equations of the tangent lines are $y=2x-1$ and $y=4x-4$. These lines are tangent to the points $(1,1)$, $(2,3)$ and $(2,4)$, $(1,0)$. They intersect at the point $(1.5, 2)$.

I noticed that setting the first derivatives of both quadratics ($y'=2x$ & $y'=-2x+6$) equal to each other you find $x=6/4$. Is their any significance to the fact that the point of intersect for the tangents is at the midpoint between the two parabolas at $x=1.5$? My professor said that this is the point at which the two graphs are parallel. Is this a special case, or the norm, for two quadratic equations? Is it used in other scenarios, or proofs?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the two parabolas have equations $y_1=x^2+bx+h$ and $y_2=-x^2+cx+k,$ and are situated so there are in fact two common tangents which intersect somewhere "outside" both parabolas (outside is parts below the first and above the second as in your case). The $x$ coordinates of the vertices of $y_1,y_2$ are respectively $-b/2,+c/2.$

Now note that if we define $h(x)=(y1-y2)'=4x+(b-c),$  at the two vertices we have $h(-b/2)=-b-c$ and $h(c/2)=b+c.$ Since the second derivative (the derivative of $h$) is the constant $4,$ the function $h$ increases at a constant rate between the two vertices, and so  one gets $h=0$ at the point $m$ which is the midpoint of the $x$ coordinates of the two vertices.

Comment: I know when given a single point outside a parabola there are only two lines tangent to the parabola which intersect at that given point. Is there not always two tangents (and only two) which touch both parabolas and which intersect at the shortest midpoint?

Comment: @Zuriel I think you're right, just as in your example there are (when the two outsides have nonempty intersection) two common tangents. I also think that if one is "up" and the other "down" with the same $x^2$ coefficicient, that the $x$ coordinate of the crossing point of the two tangents will be at the midpoint of the x-cords of the two vertices. Myself I need to do more to really "show" this is true, i.e. why should the two parabolas have the same slopes when the crossing point x value is plugged in...

Comment: One thing I noticed is that $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2+6x-5$ are transformations of each other which, I think, is what you are saying in the second sentence. Would it be easier to show when this is not true, like a null hypothesis? How would one find a null hypothesis?